# complex parsing with regex and building a dictionary

Tags: python, regex

my code looks like

```
import re
import json
from collections import defaultdict

config = '''
#
acl number 2040 name jerry
 rule 0 permit source 192.5.0.21 0
 rule 10 permit tcp source 10.1.30.15 0 destination 10.100.10.25 0 destination-port eq 123
 rule 65534 deny ip
acl number 2111
 rule 5 permit vpn-instance tom source 192.85.247.111 0
#
acl number 3045 name bugs
 rule 0 permit tcp source 10.1.2.12 0 destination 10.1.4.12 0 destination-port eq 22
 rule 10 permit tcp source 10.1.22.12 0 destination 10.1.44.12 0 destination-port eq 123
 rule 20 permit tcp source 192.85.5.22 0 destination 10.1.5.110 0 destination-port eq 443
 rule 65534 deny ip
acl number 3050 name woody
 rule 0 permit ip destination 192.5.49.21 0
 rule 65534 deny ip
#
'''


acl_to_parse = []
rules_to_parse = []
acl_number = []
acl_n = []
acl_name = []
acl_desc = []
acl_description = []
hw_count = []
hardware_count = []
step = []
acl_step = []
acl_rule_id = []
acl_action = []
acl_action_word = []
parsed_acls = []


acl_pattern = re.finditer(r'(\snumber)\s(\d+)(\s(name)\s([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+))?(?s)(.*?)(\nacl|\s#)', config, flags=re.MULTILINE)

for match in acl_pattern:
    acl_to_parse.append(match.group(6))
    acl_number.append(match.group(2))
    acl_n.append(match.group(4))
    acl_name.append(match.group(5))

acl_to_parse_pattern = re.compile(r'\srule\s(\d+)\s(permit|deny)(\s(tcp|udp|ip))?(\s(source)\s(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)\s(\d+))?(\s(icmp-type)\s([a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?(\s(source-port)\s(eq)\s(\d+|\w+))?(\s(destination)\s(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)\s(\d+))?(\s(destination-port)\s(eq)\s([a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?')

for some in range(1,len(acl_number)+1):
    some = 'acls to parse'
    rules_to_parse.append(some)

acl_dic = {}

for i, index_acl_number in enumerate(acl_number):
    acl_dic[index_acl_number] = {str(acl_n[i]): acl_name[i], (rules_to_parse[i]): acl_to_parse[i]}


print(acl_dic)
```

which produces the output:

```
{'2040': {'name': 'jerry', 'acls to parse': '\n rule 0 permit source 192.5.0.21 0\n rule 10 permit tcp source 10.1.30.15 0 destination 10.100.10.25 0 destination-port eq 123\n rule 65534 deny'}, '2111': {'None': None, 'acls to parse': '\n rule 5 permit vpn-instance tom source 192.85.247.111 0'}, '3045': {'name': 'bugs', 'acls to parse': '\n rule 0 permit tcp source 10.1.2.12 0 destination 10.1.4.12 0 destination-port eq 22\n rule 10 permit tcp source 10.1.22.12 0 destination 10.1.44.12 0 destination-port eq 123\n rule 20 permit tcp source 192.85.5.22 0 destination 10.1.5.110 0 destination-port eq 443\n rule 65534 deny ip'}, '3050': {'name': 'woody', 'acls to parse': '\n rule 0 permit ip destination 192.5.49.21 0\n rule 65534 deny ip'}}
```

instead of the output above i'd like to get one similar to:

```
{'2040': {'name': 'jerry', '0':{'action':'permit', 'protocol':'none', 'source_ip':'192.5.0.21', 'source_wildcard':'0', 'destination_ip':'none', 'destination_wildcard':'none', 'destination_port':'none'}
{'2040': {'name': 'jerry', '10':{'action':'permit', 'protocol':'tcp', 'source_ip':'10.1.30.15', 'source_wildcard':'0', 'destination_ip':'10.100.10.25', 'destination_wildcard':'0', 'destination_port':'123'}
{'2040': {'name': 'jerry', '65534':{'action':'deny', 'protocol':'ip', 'source_ip':'none', 'source_wildcard':'none', 'destination_ip':'none', 'destination_wildcard':'none', 'destination_port':'none'}
```

and so forward for acl 2111, 3045 and 3050

i think i need to find a way to iterate over 'acls to parse': '\n rule 0 permit source 192.5.0.21 0\n rule 10 permit tcp source 10.1.30.15 0 destination 10.100.10.25 0 destination-port eq 123\n rule 65534 deny' and get somehow to the result mentioned above...
but i have no idea how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the way you loop over the ACLs. From the format I get that you:

1. Find an ACL
2. Keep reading rules until another ACL is defined
3. Repeat 1 and 2

So let's do that in code:

```py
import re
import json
import warnings

from typing import Dict, Optional


# Your data here...
config = """
#
acl number 2040 name jerry
 rule 0 permit source 192.5.0.21 0
 rule 10 permit tcp source 10.1.30.15 0 destination 10.100.10.25 0 destination-port eq 123
 rule 65534 deny ip
acl number 2111
 rule 5 permit vpn-instance tom source 192.85.247.111 0
#
acl number 3045 name bugs
 rule 0 permit tcp source 10.1.2.12 0 destination 10.1.4.12 0 destination-port eq 22
 rule 10 permit tcp source 10.1.22.12 0 destination 10.1.44.12 0 destination-port eq 123
 rule 20 permit tcp source 192.85.5.22 0 destination 10.1.5.110 0 destination-port eq 443
 rule 65534 deny ip
acl number 3050 name woody
 rule 0 permit ip destination 192.5.49.21 0
 rule 65534 deny ip
#
"""


# Keep track of the discovered ACL
current_acl: Optional[int] = None
acls: Dict[int, Dict] = {}

# Loop the lines in the text
for line in config.splitlines():

    # Match a new rule
    if re.match(r"^acl\s+", line):

        # Extract information about the ACL
        match = re.match(
            r"acl\s+number\s+(?P<number>\d+)(\s+name\s+(?P<name>\w+)\s*)?$", line
        )

        # Do nothing if this is not an ACL
        if match is None:
            warnings.warn(f"ACL doesn't comply with the defined regex! Skipping ACL: '{line}'")
            continue

        # Add the ACL and make it the current ACL for future rules
        current_acl = int(match["number"])
        acls[current_acl] = {
            "name": match["name"],
            "rules": {},
        }

    # Match a rule
    elif re.match(r"^\s*rule\s+", line):

        # Extract information about the rule
        match = re.match(
            r"\s*rule\s(?P<rank>\d+)\s(?P<action>permit|deny)(\s(?P<protocol>tcp|udp|ip))?(\s(source)\s(?P<source_ip>\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)\s+(?P<source_wildcard>\d+))?(\s*(icmp-type)\s([a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?(\s(source-port)\s(eq)\s(?P<source_port>\d+|\w+))?(\s(destination)\s+(?P<destination_ip>\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)\s(?P<destination_wildcard>\d+))?(\s(destination-port)\s(eq)\s(?P<destination_port>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?",
            line,
        )

        # Do nothing if the rule is not in the right format
        if match is None:
            warnings.warn(f"Rule doesn't comply with the defined regex! Skipping rule: '{line}'")
            continue

        # Do nothing if there is no ACL detected yet
        if current_acl is None:
            warnings.warn(f"Rule defined before ACL definition! Skipping rule: '{line}'")
            continue

        # Add the rule
        acls[current_acl]["rules"][int(match["rank"])] = {
            "action": match["action"],
            "protocol": match["protocol"],
            "source_ip": match["source_ip"],
            "destination_ip": match["destination_ip"],
            "destination_wildcard": match["destination_wildcard"],
            "destination_port": match["destination_port"],
        }


# Show the output
print(json.dumps(acls, indent=2))
print(acls)
```

Output:

```
{
  "2040": {
    "name": "jerry",
    "rules": {
      "0": {
        "action": "permit",
        "protocol": null,
        "source_ip": "192.5.0.21",
        "destination_ip": null,
        "destination_wildcard": null,
        "destination_port": null
      },
      "10": {
        "action": "permit",
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "source_ip": "10.1.30.15",
        "destination_ip": "10.100.10.25",
        "destination_wildcard": "0",
        "destination_port": "123"
      },
      "65534": {
        "action": "deny",
        "protocol": "ip",
        "source_ip": null,
        "destination_ip": null,
        "destination_wildcard": null,
        "destination_port": null
      }
    }
  },
  "2111": {
    "name": null,
    "rules": {
      "5": {
        "action": "permit",
        "protocol": null,
        "source_ip": null,
        "destination_ip": null,
        "destination_wildcard": null,
        "destination_port": null
      }
    }
  },
  "3045": {
    "name": "bugs",
    "rules": {
      "0": {
        "action": "permit",
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "source_ip": "10.1.2.12",
        "destination_ip": "10.1.4.12",
        "destination_wildcard": "0",
        "destination_port": "22"
      },
      "10": {
        "action": "permit",
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "source_ip": "10.1.22.12",
        "destination_ip": "10.1.44.12",
        "destination_wildcard": "0",
        "destination_port": "123"
      },
      "20": {
        "action": "permit",
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "source_ip": "192.85.5.22",
        "destination_ip": "10.1.5.110",
        "destination_wildcard": "0",
        "destination_port": "443"
      },
      "65534": {
        "action": "deny",
        "protocol": "ip",
        "source_ip": null,
        "destination_ip": null,
        "destination_wildcard": null,
        "destination_port": null
      }
    }
  },
  "3050": {
    "name": "woody",
    "rules": {
      "0": {
        "action": "permit",
        "protocol": "ip",
        "source_ip": null,
        "destination_ip": "192.5.49.21",
        "destination_wildcard": "0",
        "destination_port": null
      },
      "65534": {
        "action": "deny",
        "protocol": "ip",
        "source_ip": null,
        "destination_ip": null,
        "destination_wildcard": null,
        "destination_port": null
      }
    }
  }
}
{2040: {'name': 'jerry', 'rules': {0: {'action': 'permit', 'protocol': None, 'source_ip': '192.5.0.21', 'destination_ip': None, 'destination_wildcard': None, 'destination_port': None}, 10: {'action': 'permit', 'protocol': 'tcp', 'source_ip': '10.1.30.15', 'destination_ip': '10.100.10.25', 'destination_wildcard': '0', 'destination_port': '123'}, 65534: {'action': 'deny', 'protocol': 'ip', 'source_ip': None, 'destination_ip': None, 'destination_wildcard': None, 'destination_port': None}}}, 2111: {'name': None, 'rules': {5: {'action': 'permit', 'protocol': None, 'source_ip': None, 'destination_ip': None, 'destination_wildcard': None, 'destination_port': None}}}, 3045: {'name': 'bugs', 'rules': {0: {'action': 'permit', 'protocol': 'tcp', 'source_ip': '10.1.2.12', 'destination_ip': '10.1.4.12', 'destination_wildcard': '0', 'destination_port': '22'}, 10: {'action': 'permit', 'protocol': 'tcp', 'source_ip': '10.1.22.12', 'destination_ip': '10.1.44.12', 'destination_wildcard': '0', 'destination_port': '123'}, 20: {'action': 'permit', 'protocol': 'tcp', 'source_ip': '192.85.5.22', 'destination_ip': '10.1.5.110', 'destination_wildcard': '0', 'destination_port': '443'}, 65534: {'action': 'deny', 'protocol': 'ip', 'source_ip': None, 'destination_ip': None, 'destination_wildcard': None, 'destination_port': None}}}, 3050: {'name': 'woody', 'rules': {0: {'action': 'permit', 'protocol': 'ip', 'source_ip': None, 'destination_ip': '192.5.49.21', 'destination_wildcard': '0', 'destination_port': None}, 65534: {'action': 'deny', 'protocol': 'ip', 'source_ip': None, 'destination_ip': None, 'destination_wildcard': None, 'destination_port': None}}}}
```

NOTE: JSON doesn't allow keys to be anything other than `str`. However, the keys are in fact `int`s.